# Someone Ripped Me Off, Please Help Calculating Odds!!

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm protesting a state contract, and one of the grounds for protest is that someone stole material from a past proposal my company submitted, and is representing it as their own.  Besides leaving our company's name on one of "their" documents, we found a claim number that they forgot to change on one of their submissions.  It is listed as a two digit number, followed by a hyphen, followed by a 6 digit number.  Example: 34-647385.  What are the odds of them choosing that exact sequence for their document?  I need a math genius to help me out!!  Thank you.  -Mike

Comment: $\frac{1}{9^8} = \frac{1}{43046721} \approx $ chance to win to the lottery. But please have a look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and edit your question in consequence.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what valid claim numbers are.

If the digits are randomly generated then the odds of them putting that one down are one in $100$ million.  If the claim number needs to start in $34-$ then it's one in a million.

But, I think this is just a couple of nails in a big coffin for your case.  Having your company's name on the document is much more incriminating.  Placed in probabilistic terms:  Given that they have *your* company's name on *their* document, the probability that they copied your proposal is very close to $1$.

Comment: Also, we can safely assume that these aren't independent events.